# Spring Boot Mixpanel : How to set properties to User profile?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mixpanel

Now I am writing a application to send event to Mixpanel using Spring Boot and I currently can only set properties to event but not User profile.

```
        MessageBuilder messages = new MessageBuilder("my token");
        JSONObject eventProp = new JSONObject();
        eventProp.put("City", "Phnom Penh");
        JSONObject event = messages.event("joe@gribbl.com", "Logged In", eventProp);

        ClientDelivery delivery = new ClientDelivery();
        delivery.addMessage(event);

        MixpanelAPI mixpanel = new MixpanelAPI();
        mixpanel.deliver(delivery);
```

How to set properties to that user profile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update/set properties for people by [messageBuilder.set](http://mixpanel.github.io/mixpanel-java/com/mixpanel/mixpanelapi/MessageBuilder.html#set(java.lang.String,%20org.json.JSONObject))

```
        MessageBuilder messages = new MessageBuilder("my token");
        // prepare event properties
        JSONObject eventProp = new JSONObject();
        eventProp.put("City", "Phnom Penh");
        JSONObject event = messages.event("joe@gribbl.com", "Logged In", eventProp);

        // prepare people properties
        JSONObject peopleProp = new JSONObject();
        peopleProp.put("Full Name", "Cheav Sovannarith");
        JSONObject people = messages.event("joe@gribbl.com", peopleProp);

        ClientDelivery delivery = new ClientDelivery();
        delivery.addMessage(event);
        delivery.addMessage(people);

        MixpanelAPI mixpanel = new MixpanelAPI();
        mixpanel.deliver(delivery);
```

READ MORE [developer.mixpanel.com](https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/java#section-setting-profile-properties)